# Selenium driver - select the desired li item in the list

Tags: java, selenium

In a list of 8 Elements I would select the one that contains the search text in children div. I need this because the elements of the list changes order every time. Here I would like to select the one that contains the text "TITLE TO LISTEN". How do I scroll through the list and select the wish li?

Thanks in advance

Here one li:

```
...
                    <li id="3636863298979137009" class="clearfix" data-size="1" data-fixed="1" data-side="r">
                        <div class="userContentWrapper">
                            <div class="jki">
                                <span class="userContent">
                                    TITLE TO LISTEN
                            </div>                                              
                            <div class="TimelineUFI uiContainer">
                                <form id="u_0_b0" class="able_item collapsed_s autoexpand_mode" onsubmit="return window.Event && E" action="/ajax/ufi/modify.php" method="post" >                                       
                                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="data_only_response" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="TimelineFeedbackHeader">
                                        <a class="ction_link" role="button" title="Journal" data-ft="{"tn":"J","type":25}" rel="dialog" href="/ajax/" tabindex="0" rip-style-bordercolor-backup="" style="" rip-style-borderstyle-backup="" >LISTEN</a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            ...
```

I tried this code, but it don't work because the elements ids change each time.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/span[2]/a")).click();
```

For example:

```
If text contain "TEXT TO LISTEN":   li[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span
Link "listen" i want to click :     li[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/span[2]/a
```

here is number 3, but the order may change. I would first like to get that number and then click on the right link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get list of all li elements, and then search for specified text

```
 for(int i=0; i< listOfLiElements.Count, i++){
 if(listOfLiElements[i].FindElement(By.ClassName("userContent")).Text == "TITLE TO LISTEN")
     {
      correctElement = listOfLiElements[i].FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
      i =listOfLiElements.Count;
     }
 }
```

Comment: all li element have the same link(href) named "listen". To differentiate it must look if the tag "<span class="userContent">" contains the text "TITLE TO LISTEN".

Comment: so try with comparing text of span element - see edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Your text goes here')]"))
```

EDIT: just realised it's very old ques and you might have got ans by now, so for others who are looking for answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, then just iterate through for each and ask if the current element has the right text inside it.

```
List<Element> listOfLiTags = driver.findElement(By.Id("yourUlId")).findElements(By.TagName("li"));
for(Element li : listOfLiTags) {
    String text = li.getElement(By.ClassName("userContent").getText();
    if(text.equals("TITLE TO LISTEN") {
        //do whatever you want and don't forget break
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this is much more easier with [CssSelector API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByCssSelector.html).

```
List<Element> listOfSpans = driver.findElements(
   By.CssSelector("ul[id=yourId] li span[class=userContent]");
```

Now just iterate and ask for the right text:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
     public void ClickLink()
{
   WebElement ol =driver.findElement(By.id("ol"));
   List<WebElement> lis=ol.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
   ArrayList<String> listFromGUI=new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0;i<lis.size();i++)
   {
     WebElement li=ol.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='ol']/li["+(i+1)+"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span"));
     if(li.getText().trim().equals("TEXT TO LISTEN"))
     {
         WebElement link=ol.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='ol']/li["+(i+1)+"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/span[2]/a"));
         if(link.getText().trim().equals("LISTEN"))
         {
             link.click();
             break;
         }
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: In this firstly we are finding an ordered list and then we are finding all the li in that particulat ol(You have 8 li so u jusy have to give the id of the Ol which contains all these li's). Then we are checking if the li sleceted text is equal to "TEXT TO LISTEN" .If it is we are checking the link text weather it is equal to "LISTEN". If it is we click on that link and comes out of the loop.